# Setting up local to make ajax calls to node server

Tags: node.js, local, environment

I am sure that this question might be very obvious but not sure what to search for the answer.

I have some local running client side code (on anvil server), which for those unfamiliar is a tool for loading static files simply on OSX (http://anvilformac.com/). So my site is for instance ... example.dev.

I want this to talk to my node server running on local host 127.0.0.1:3000 (or whatever port).

This is going to give me issues with cross domain (I think).

How do I setup my local environment so that I can make this possible? Do I need to setup some apache server i.e MAMP? or some virtual machine to make this work?

I also don't want to use JSONP.

Thanks in advance.

I.e making my request will return: XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3127.0.0.1:3000/user/listall. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

What headers do I need to set to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) requests for this.

EDIT: set jsonp property to false if you don't want it.

Comment: Sure, I am aware of jQuery AJAX, but that doesn't enable me to make CORS requests?

Comment: I missed that sorry. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) article discusses http access control that should answer your question